# How to disable middle mouse click paste in Atom editor?

Tags: electron, atom-editor

I did extensive investigations but didn't find a way to disable the middle mouse click paste.

I have found it was possible to disable Auxclick but it has no effect into the Atom editor:

`atom --disable-blink-features=Auxclick`

Can you help? The middle mouse click paste can be extremely annoying.

Comment: For the people requesting  to close the question, may I remind you that I use Atom to develop software and thus it is a valid question on SO.
...software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development...
It is extremely annoying to click on the mouse wheel button and that the code is screwed by unwanted paste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and as I couldn't find a solution, I've developed an extension to disable it:

https://atom.io/packages/disable-middle-click-paste

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realized until now that I was inserting text with my mouse. I thought it was because of my very sensitive keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for the work and the answer! Using the trackpoint on a thinkpad where the middle button scrolls really messed things up for me until this :D